# InvalidOperationException: Session has not been configured for this application or request

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

i am setting up a new application and wants to store the complaint of a customer by using session. For Session i use email as session ID

I am using database SQL, ASP MVC version 2.1, also using this service in startup file "services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);"

Startup file`enter code here`

```
public class Startup
    {
         public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add 
          services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
            {
                // This lambda determines whether user consent for non- 
                essential cookies is needed for a given request.
                options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
                options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
            });
```

services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

```
        services.AddSingleton<ICustomerRepository, CustomerRepository>();
      services.AddSingleton<IComplaintRepository, ComplaintRepository>();
          services.AddSingleton<IAdminRepository, AdminRepository>();

        services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
        services.AddSession();
        services.AddMvc();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to 
   configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
       {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            app.UseHsts();
        }
        app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseCookiePolicy();
        app.UseSession();
        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
}
```

Controller file having Signup function`enter code here`

```
    public IActionResult Signup()
        {
            if (HttpContext.Session.GetString("email") != null)
            {
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            else
            {
                 return View();
            }
        }


    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Signup([Bind("CustomerEmail", "CustomerName", "CustomerContact", "CustomerAddress", "CustomerPassword", "ConfirmPassword")] Customer customer)
    {
        if (customer.ConfirmPassword != customer.CustomerPassword)
        {
            ViewBag.Error = "Your password and confirm password doesn't match";
            return View();
        }

        if (_customer.EmailExist(customer.CustomerEmail))
        {
            ViewBag.Error = "Account with this email already exist, please Login to your account or register with different email";
            return View();
        }

        if (_customer.RegisterCustomer(customer))
        {
            HttpContext.Session.SetString("email", customer.CustomerEmail);
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));

        }
        else
        {
            return View();
        }

    }
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: having error : InvalidOperationException: Session has not been configured for this application or request

Answer (score 3):

You are configuring two mvc middlewares by `app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();` and `app.UseMvc`. First choose your expected one and remove another. The key issue is that you are placing `app.UseSession();` after `app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();` which will cause Session middleware fail to execute. Try to move `app.UseSession();` before `app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();`.